# Bonferroni correction: control vs. groups?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, inference, resampling

I'm trying to understand how to set up a Bonferroni correction on several different groups and compare it to the control group.

The groups and observations are as follows (with Group 0 being the control):

Group $\hspace{5mm}$  Observations
0$\hspace{15mm}$  97.76$\hspace{5mm}$ 102.56$\hspace{5mm}$ 96.08$\hspace{5mm}$ 125.12
1$\hspace{15mm}$  91.28$\hspace{5mm}$ 129.20$\hspace{5mm}$ 90.80$\hspace{5mm}$  72.32
2$\hspace{15mm}$  67.28$\hspace{5mm}$  85.76$\hspace{5mm}$ 95.60$\hspace{5mm}$  73.28
3$\hspace{15mm}$  80.24 $\hspace{5mm}$ 64.88 $\hspace{5mm}$64.88 $\hspace{5mm}$ 78.56
4$\hspace{15mm}$  96.08$\hspace{5mm}$  98.24 $\hspace{5mm}$77.84 $\hspace{5mm}$ 95.36
5$\hspace{15mm}$  57.68 $\hspace{5mm}$ 89.84$\hspace{5mm}$ 98.48 $\hspace{5mm}$ 92.72
6$\hspace{15mm}$  68.72  $\hspace{5mm}$85.28 $\hspace{5mm}$68.72 $\hspace{5mm}$ 74.24

I know typically the Bonferroni correction works by multiplying probabilities by the total number of probabilities and then comparing the new value to the critical value.

However, I am not familiar with how to perform a Bonferroni with several groups (and subsequent observations within each group).

Comment: Count how many comparisons you'll be making, then divide the designated type I error rate by that number. Use the answer as your new threshold for hypothesis testing. For instance, p < 0.05 for one test, p < 0.025 for two tests, p < 0.005 for 10 tests.

Comment: You might want to look into Dunnett's test, which is specifically designed to control the experiment-wise error rate when several treatments are compared pair-wise to a control.

Comment: I did a two sample t-test with the R function t.test comparing each group to the control group. My results for the p-values were: 

.5217,.03596,.008419,.157,.1231,.01107

I then used the p.ajust method to obtain the following:

1.000000 0.215760 0.050514 0.942000 0.738600 0.066420

I concluded that none of the p-values were significant at the alpha=.05 level.